# In Perl, how can I block for a bunch of system calls to finish?

Tags: perl

I'm doing a bunch of system calls that I want to run in parallel:

```
system(" sleep 5 && echo step 1 done &");
system(" sleep 3 && echo step 2 done &");
system(" sleep 7 && echo step 3 done &");

// block here
```

How can I block the program flow until all the system calls are finished?

Comment: does the parent perl script need to parse the output?
your post doesn't imply that requirement, but every time I've had to do this, managing the output was also a requirement.  Using magic open with pipes and select to read them back worked well for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to `fork` a new child process for each system call, and then wait for them to finish. Here's a simplified example:

```
my @commands = ( "sleep 5 && echo step 1 done",
                 "sleep 3 && echo step 2 done",
                 "sleep 7 && echo step 3 done" );

my @pids;
foreach my $cmd( @commands ) {
    my $pid = fork;
    if ( $pid ) {
        # parent process
        push @pids, $pid;
        next;
    }

    # now we're in the child
    system( $cmd );
    exit;            # terminate the child
}

wait for @pids;   # wait for each child to terminate

print "all done.\n";
```

Comment: Perfect.  I know I should suffer more and synthesize the answer on my own... but my perl is pretty rusty.  Thank you for this snippet.

Comment: It would bloat the example so I don't want to complain much, but if `fork` fails, it returns `undef` which is false, and then this code does the wrong thing.  Also, I'd vote for using `exec` instead of `system+exit` - Perl's `exec` does allow you to give it a full string for the shell such as these.

Answer (score 4):

Fork a child process to perform each job, and in the parent, wait for those processes to finish before exiting.

See [perldoc perlfork](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html), [perldoc -f fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) and [perldoc -f waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html).

(The exact code for this is left as an exercise for the reader -- everyone should have to write this from scratch at least once, to understand the details involved. There are lots of examples on this site as well.)

Comment: It may be good advice, but "rtfm" is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

what about running each one of the system call from a different  thread and join on the threads

Comment: Threads are rarely a good idea in general, IME. And they're an especially ungood idea in Perl, whose threads are a gigantic pain in the ass. The `fork` solution is probably best.

Comment: The perl version we're using for my project doesn't have "thread"
support and I don't use perl much so I'm not going to try to migrate our project.  Thanks for the suggestion though.