# Threading with Perl, how can I execute my thread at the same time

Tags: perl

I need to execute ~500 threads all at the same time and below is the code that I currently developed. The issue that I am running into is that my threads are being executed one after another (not async).

The code below essentially runs through a loop of symbols that tells what type of thread to execute, BUT I need them to start at the same time.

```
no warnings;
while ( my $row =
       shift( @{$rowcache} )
    || shift( @{ $rowcache = $sth->fetchall_arrayref( undef, $max_rows ) } ) )
{    
    my $prod_filter = "perl /home/zad0xlik/qtrack/1.2.v.chain_pg_sputnik.pl @{$row} " . lc(substr(join('', @{$row}), 0, 1)) . "_optsputnik";

    @running = threads->list(threads::running);
    print "LOOP $i\n";
    print "  - BEGIN LOOP >> NB running threads = "
      . ( scalar @running ) . "\n";

    if ( scalar @running < $nb_process ) {

        my $thread = threads->new( sub { system( ${prod_filter} ); } );

        #my $thread = threads->new( sub { sleeping_sub($i, \@a, \@b) });
        push( @Threads, $thread );
        my $tid = $thread->tid;
        print "  - starting thread $tid\n";
    }
    @running = threads->list(threads::running);
    print "  - AFTER STARTING >> NB running Threads = "
      . ( scalar @running ) . "\n";
    foreach my $thr (@Threads) {
        if ( $thr->is_running() ) {
            my $tid = $thr->tid;
            print "  - Thread $tid running\n";
        }
        elsif ( $thr->is_joinable() ) {
            my $tid = $thr->tid;
            $thr->join;
            print "  - Results for thread $tid:\n";
            print "  - Thread $tid has been joined\n";
        }
    }

    @running = threads->list(threads::running);
    print "  - END LOOP >> NB Threads = " . ( scalar @running ) . "\n";
    $i++;

}

print "\nJOINING pending threads\n";
while ( scalar @running != 0 ) {
    foreach my $thr (@Threads) {
        $thr->join if ( $thr->is_joinable() );
    }
    @running = threads->list(threads::running);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I manage multiple subprocesses in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322822/how-do-i-manage-multiple-subprocesses-in-perl) (The accepted answer is a direct answer to your question -- you shouldn't be using threads for this.)

Comment: You cannot execute 500 of anything at the same time, not with Perl for sure. (Even in C or C++ 500 threads would push it way too far.)  In particular, threads in Perl are very heavy.  If this is critical for your purpose, you'll have to go back to the drawing board. If it is not, consider the post linked by @duskwuff in their comment -- you'll want the `Parallel::ForkManager` metioned there, to keep a certain number of forked processes running.  You could use thread queues but it's tricky territory in Perl, to say the least.

Comment: As for your direct question -- I am not sure what you mean by "at the same time."  If you mean that you are getting sequential execution, try `threads->create` (or `async`) instead of using `new` (I've never used `new` so I don't know what it does).  If you mean that you want them to _start_ at the exact same time, you can't have that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I wonder why 500 threads would be a push if the hardware should support it. When I say "at the same time", I want my threads to start at not exact time but once they all start to work simultaneously parallel to each other with relatively equal priority. Meaning, I don't want thread x to capture data at a faster rate than thread y.

Comment: @zdim `thread->new` starts a new thread running. That isn't the problem here.

Comment: @zad0xlik  OK, thanks for clarification -- so you just want normal concurrent processing.  Is there a need for real-time action by the script? If not, you can keep a pool of processes that fetch data in a rolling manner -- and tag their catch with timestamps.  Then every half a second or a second you can sort them and report their outputs at the "same" (more or less) time.  So there would be a lag but you'd get results as they were at the same time (half a second or a second ago each time).

Comment: @zad0xlik  Just try to fork 500 times and see what happens. I'd suggest you make sure there is nothing of value running at a time, since if resources are abused by forking nothing's off limits (you may even end up needing to push the button to restart).  Clearly, it surely won't really run all in parallel, unless you have 500 cores (even if you did I don't know that there is I/O system that can do that).  _Do not try this with threads_ though. They're much heavier in Perl.  To improve your chances you can write C code that does this; then do use threads (and still be ready to reboot).

Comment: Thanks zdim, I think I would need to port over my code to C to make it faster and to use threads. Launched all 500 at ones multiple times and certain threads don't even get to being executed. Should I use C or maybe Rust? Do you know if there is an easy way to port over Perl code to C?

Comment: @zad0xlik   I just saw your last comment accidentally -- please tag the username with the "at" symbol ("ATusername") so user is notified.  As for porting Perl to C, you'll need to just write the C code. It's going to be a bit different of course.  Don't know about Rust, haven't used it myself. I would _not_ rely on 500 things running at the same time, even if it works.  Note again, they can't really unless there's 500 cores and monster hardware. (And I still don't think that they can all go together.) If you ran Perl code with 500 _threads_ you are lucky that some merely didn't execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. You've really misunderstood how threads work in perl. They aren't lightweight. You shouldn't be using 500 of them.

... and even if you did, threading to call `system` to run another perl script is a bad solution. And 500 concurrent would require 500 processors to run all at once. So they'll all queue anyway.

If you really want to do threading, I'd suggest a [worker threads model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons), where you spawn 2 threads per core, and queue work to them.

As for all starting at 'the same time' - the answer here would be to instantiate your threads first, and use a [semaphore](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Semaphore.html) to start them going.

But I'd really suggest you ask another question, outlining what you're trying to accomplish (and offer the code so far) as I'm pretty sure there'll be a better approach than 500 threads.

In particular - I would be thinking that you want to just open an exec filehandle, and use `IO::Select` to read from your subprocessess.

E.g.:

```
while ( stuff ) { #e.g. your query
  open ( my $data, '-|,' $prod_filter ); 
  push @all_filehandles, $data;  
}
my $select = IO::Select -> new ( @all_filehandles ); 

while ( my @readable = $select -> can_read ) {
    foreach my $fh ( @readable ) { 
       my $line = <$fh>;
       print $line;
    }
}
```

Something like that at any rate.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique and I am trying the approaches you suggested. The reason 500 threads is because I have that many stock options that I need to track tick by tick change. Unfortunately, the exchange does not accept multiple stock requests at one time for options data, but one request for each stock. So I have to create these many connections (the code that is being threaded) to start tracking them simultaneously.

Comment: That sounds like a really good way to DOS your exchange, and will upset them hugely.

Comment: Well at least I got that going for me.