# How to launch many programs sequentially without being block?

Tags: perl

In unix system

I have a directory called program_sets , and in the program_sets , there exists 8 directory and in each directory they have a program called A.pl

I want to launch and run 8 A.pl programs in the same time , but when I launch the first program , the procedure will be block until the first program call is finish . How can I solve this problems?

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

opendir(Programs,"./program_sets");
@Each_names = readdir(Programs);
shift(@Each_names);
shift(@Each_names);

for($i=0;$i<=$#Each_names;$i++)
{
    `perl ./program_sets/$Each_names[$i]/A.pl`;
}
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Perl, how can I block for a bunch of system calls to finish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231833/in-perl-how-can-i-block-for-a-bunch-of-system-calls-to-finish)

Comment: @Thilo No, that question is about how to wait, he doesn't want to wait.

Comment: Running in *n*x or Windows?

Comment: @Barmar: It is about how to wait after launching them in parallel. Which seems to apply here.

Comment: @Thilo His question is how to launch them in parallel in the first place.

Comment: ... which the answers over there seem to do (using fork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run them in the background with `&`, just like you would from the shell.

```
for($i=0;$i<=$#Each_names;$i++)
{
    system("perl ./program_sets/$Each_names[$i]/A.pl >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
```

Also, backticks should be used when you're assigning the output to a variable. Use `system()` to run a command without saving the output.

Answer (score 0):

In *NIX, you can add "&" to the command-line to launch the programs in the background.

Another option is to use fork() http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html

Answer (score 0):

There looks to be some other issues here as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# warnings, strict
use warnings;
use strict;

# lexically scoped $dh
#opendir(Programs,"./program_sets");
my $cur_dir = "./program_sets";
opendir(my $dh, $cur_dir);

# what exactly is being shifted off here? "." and ".."??
#@Each_names = readdir(Programs);
#shift(@Each_names);
#shift(@Each_names);

# I would replace these three lines with a grep and a meaningful name.
# -d: only directories. /^\./: Anything that begins with a "." 
# eg. hidden files, "." and ".."
my @dirs = grep{ -d && $_ !~ /^\./ } readdir $dh;
close $dh;

for my $dir ( @dirs ) {
    my $path = "$cur_dir/$dir";

    system("perl $path/A.pl >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
```

Comment: @user2131116 - even if that somehow works, last I checked `readdir` doesn't sort, it's the wrong way to do it with 2 `shifts`. This would also fail if you ever add any additional files to your directory including `hidden` files. See the comments I've left by the changes.

Comment: if I sort the array of readdir , then shift the two elements of head , then it must be shift . or .. right?

Comment: @user2131116 - I believe a `sort` would make the `shift` `shit` work. But why would you want to do that? This is exactly what `grep` is for. Your `shift`'s won't work if you have any files(hidden files also) in `./program_set` other than the 8 dirs with `a.pl`. Read my comments

Comment: @user2131116 - I forgot to add that the `perl` script in question will be in your list(`@Each_names`). Which means at some point, the `system` call will be `perl ./program_sets/{your_perl_script.pl}/A.pl`. So again, the `grep` in my answer will take care of that bug too.