# Fork in a loop. Simultaneous process

Tags: perl, loops, process

I Didn't quite understand the fork function.

How could i print output from the files simultaneously, use separate process for each file?

```
my $regex = $ARGV[0];

for (@ARGV[1 .. $#ARGV]){
        open (my $fh, "<", $_);
        foreach (<$fh>){
               print "$1\n" if $_ =~ /(\b$regex\b)/;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Very similar question here with good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231833/in-perl-how-can-i-block-for-a-bunch-of-system-calls-to-finish/2232057

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you also want to limit the number of simultaneous processes. [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) makes this easy.

```
use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($MAX_PROCESSES);

my $filter = shift(@ARGV);
$filter = qr/$filter/;

for my $qfn (@ARGV) {
   $pm->start() and next;

   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      print "$1\n" if /(\b$regex\b)/;
   }
}

$pm->finish();
```

If you didn't want to limit the number of simultaneous processes, it would look really similar.

```
my $filter = shift(@ARGV);
$filter = qr/$filter/;

for my $qfn (@ARGV) {
   fork() and next;

   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      print "$1\n" if /(\b$regex\b)/;
   }
}

1 while wait() > 0;
```

Comment: and how can i limit the number of processes using the **flock**?

Comment: @sliddy, Waits for the children to end.

Comment: @sliddy, `flock` is used to control access, and more specifically, to provide mutual exclusion. There's only one process creating processes, so `flock` would be completely useless.